# Why Div is not visible on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

in my webpage i set visibility of a div hidden and i want to show it on button click,so i am writing a jquery code for it.
but some how it is not working
my asp code is

```
<asp:Button ID="btnGenerate" CssClass="button" runat="server" Text="Generate" OnClick="btnGenerate_Click" />
<div id="print" style="width: 80%; margin-left: 10%; margin-top: 20px;visibility:hidden;">                
    <input type="button" id="btnPrint" class="button" value="Print" onclick="printDiv('ReportDiv')"/>
</div>
```

and my jquery code for it is:

```
 <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#btnGenerate").click(function () {
            $("#print").css("visibility", "visible");
        });
    });
</script>
```

please help me to fix this issue.
Thanks

Comment: Why not use `.show()`?

Comment: +1 ^ yep - `$("#btnPrint, #print").show()` (throwing in both of them to the selector because theres probally some asp behind the scenes stuff goin on there..)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try it

```
<script>
      $(document).ready(function () {
          $("#<%= btnGenerate.ClientID %>").click(function () {
             $("#print").css("visibility", "visible");
          });
      });
</script>
```

you can not get asp.net button click in jquery using `$("#btnGenerate")` if you want to use asp.net button in jquery then you will have to use like this `$("#<%= btnGenerate.ClientID %>")`

Answer (score 1):

Because you gave a wrong ID, Look at your html `<div id="print" ...`

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#btnGenerate").click(function () {
        $("#print").css("visibility", "visible");
    });
});
```

Comment: what is difference between your code and @akvickyit7?

Comment: @GovindaRajbhar Oh.. How clever you are? Found a bug in my code after the OP's update...

Answer (score 0):

child element will not be visible until his parent element is visible. So you need to show parent div.

Here parent div #print is hidden and you are trying to show its child div #btnPrint you have to make parent div #print visible.

try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#btnGenerate").click(function () {
            $("#print").css("visibility", "visible");
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Because .net will change the id while rendering, being runat server. You should use class for that

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".button").click(function () {
        $("#print").css("visibility", "visible");
    });
});
```

Comment: the problem is that i have many button control in my page and all button has same css class "button"